# regex to grab url from string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this json object

```
arr[i].text
```

which returns

```
check this http://www.newlook.com/shop/womens/dresses/navy-short-sleeve-check-tunic-dress-_320165649
```

I want to return only the URL with a regex like so:

```
 var urlreg = /(\bhttps?\:\/\/(www)?\.\w+\.\w+(\/[\w\d\-]+)*)/; 
match = urlreg.exec(arr[i].text );
```

but doesn't work, is it something to with it being an object and not  a string?

Comment: Works for me `'check this http://www.newlook.com/shop/womens/dresses/navy-short-sleeve-check-tunic-dress-_320165649'.match(/(\bhttps?\:\/\/(www)?\.\w+\.\w+(\/[\w\d\-]+)*)/)[1]`

Comment: Can you show us the JSON string?

Comment: What if you do it like `match = urlreg.exec(""+arr[i].text);`? See http://jsfiddle.net/zdyksaft/, your regex is working with a simple string input.

Comment: Works for me too. However, this regex can be more generalised for domain/subdomain matching. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `var urlreg = /(https?:\/\/(\w+\.)+\w+(\/[\w\-_]+)+)/\/?`

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/zE4eQ5/1#javascript)